# Firestore cloud function long time

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to do something like this, but I always get timeout. It is a long process that can take more than 9 minutes. What alternatives do I have?

```
exports.createIdsSchedule = functions.region('europe-west1').runWith(
    {
        timeoutSeconds: 540,
        memory: '4GB'
    }).pubsub.schedule('every 15 minutes')
    .timeZone('Europe/Madrid')
    .onRun(async (context) => {
        try {
            let ids = await function();
            let otherIds = await function();
            

            for (const id of ids) {
                for (const otherId of otherIds) {
                    if (id !== otherId) {
                     var followingD = await db.collection(userfollowingcollection)
                        .doc(id)
                        .collection(followingcollection)
                        .doc(otherId)
                        .get();
                        
                    var followerD = await db.collection(userfollowercollection)
                        .doc(id)
                        .collection(followercollection)
                        .doc(otherId)
                        .get();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: How long can it take? Can, all the workloads be done in parallel? Or must it be sequential?

Comment: Actually these 2 lists contain the same ids but I have to do that check with different ids as in the example. But that iteration occurs more times than the number of ids there are.

Comment: Did you have consider PubSub to achieve that? I think you can perform the first loop in parallel, no?

Comment: an example of the parallel loop?

Comment: Instead of await the action in the for loop (1st one, with ids) you can call the API in background and don't wait the return. At the end, wait for all the call that you did. Like that, the id1 and the id2 element in the collection will be updated in the same time and you will same time. Does make sense?

Comment: I'm a little lost I don't know how to approach this

Comment: What are you doing with your followingD and followerD variables? What is your subsequent logic?

Comment: its later logic is to check that both documents exist and if so, create the chat between the two of them. This code is basically a "patch" to a bug in our application that occurred with the chat. It is to fix it with the users that are active.

Comment: I have to tell you that I already solved it